# ValueError in For Loop's If Condition with two boolean arrays

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, valueerror

I'm running a For-Loop with an If Statement including two boolean Arrays to create a new array.

I already tried all Solutions I could find on StackOverflow, exchanging the & with Logical_and or bitwise_and, also using the suggested a.any() & a.all() methods, I still get the same ValueError.

```py
y_valid = [True, False, True, False, False, True]
y_pred = [False, False, True, True, False, False]

for i in (y_valid, y_pred):
    CM = []
    if (y_valid[i] == False) & (y_pred[i] == False):
        CM == 0
    elif (y_valid[i] == False) & (y_pred[i] == True):
        CM == 1
    elif (y_valid[i] == True) & (y_pred[i] == False):
        CM == 2
    elif (y_valid[i] == True) & (y_pred[i] == True):
        CM == 3
```

I expect to get an array CM including numerals from 0-3

My Output:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-107-259ac7895185> in <module>
      1 for i in (y_valid, y_pred):
      2     CM = []
----> 3     if (y_valid[i] == False) & (y_pred[i] == False):
      4         CM == 0
      5     elif (y_valid[i] == False) & (y_pred[i] == True):

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Comment: I think there are a few issues with the code above: (1) for loop `i` - what is its expected value? From what I see, `i` is a list! (2) `CM == 3`: did you mean `CM.append(3)` or `CM = 3`? (3) Python bool comparison is not really necessary (`if y_value[i] and not y_pred[i])` should work and finally (4) did you mean `and` instead of `&`?

Comment: sorry I'm newbie. I don't really know the difference, between CM == 3 or CM.append(3). I want to assign the integer value to the CM array given to the if-statement. I tried the Code with append and it worked, but I only recieved one value in CM instead of the same length as y_valid and y_pred.

Comment: No worries @Changer we all start somewhere :). Based on your comment, I posted an answer which will return an array/list in CM. Explained my changes in the comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want the following:

```
y_valid = [True, False, True, False, False, True]
y_pred = [False, False, True, True, False, False]

# Move this out of the loop so you do not reset it every time!
CM = []

# To make i integer (as required for it to be list index) 
# use range and len.
for i in range(len(y_valid)):
    # Dropping comparisons with True/False values since 
    # the following would be the same. Also note that `&` is 
    # a bitwise operator in python while `and` is boolean
    if not y_valid[i] and not y_pred[i]:
        # In every iteration we are now appending to the same CM list
        CM.append(0)
    elif not y_valid[i] and y_pred[i]:
        CM.append(1)
    elif y_valid[i] and not y_pred[i]:
        CM.append(2)
    elif y_valid[i] and y_pred[i]:
        CM.append(3)

print(CM)
```

The output is:

```
$ python /tmp/test.py 
[2, 0, 3, 1, 0, 2]
```

Checkout the comments in the code for the changes I made to the original one. Let me know if you have questions

Comment: thanks a lot this worked out fine! Good Explanation :)

Answer (score 1):

Your error is in the looping. You are iterating over a list of truth statements, which is why you get the error related to using `any()` or `all()`, as you need to define whether you want to see if there's `any()` True values or `all()` True values in the conditional.

```
y_valid = [True, False, True, False, False, True]
y_pred = [False, False, True, True, False, False]

for i in (y_valid, y_pred):
    print(i)
    break

[Out]: [True, False, True, False, False, True]
```

A faster way to do this is to zip the values in the array.
Zipping the values creates a list of tuples to iterate over:

```
y_valid = [True, False, True, False, False, True]
y_pred = [False, False, True, True, False, False]

print(list(zip(y_valid, y_pred)))

[Out]: [(True, False), (False, False), (True, True), (False, True), (False, False), (True, False)]
```

Lastly, you may want to store the values at each point in the list. In this case, you need to modify the assignment as follows:

```
CM = []
for valid, pred in zip(y_valid, y_pred):
    if not valid and not pred:
        CM.append(0)
    elif not valid and pred:
        CM.append(1)
    elif valid and not pred:
        CM.append(2)
    else:
        CM.append(3)
```

Comment: I'm getting a Syntax Error in Line 3 (if not valid & not pred:)

Comment: true - you need to use `and`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the fact that boolean can be cast to integers:

```
not y_valid[i] and not y_pred[i] => int(y_valid[i]) == 0 and int(y_pred[i]) == 0 => 2*y_valid[i] + y_pred[i] == 0
not y_valid[i] and y_pred[i]     => int(y_valid[i]) == 0 and int(y_pred[i]) == 1 => 2*y_valid[i] + y_pred[i] == 1
y_valid[i] and not y_pred[i]     => int(y_valid[i]) == 1 and int(y_pred[i]) == 0 => 2*y_valid[i] + y_pred[i] == 2
y_valid[i] and y_pred[i]         => int(y_valid[i]) == 1 and int(y_pred[i]) == 1 => 2*y_valid[i] + y_pred[i] == 3
```

And use a list comprehension to create `CM`:

```
>>> y_valid = [True, False, True, False, False, True]
>>> y_pred = [False, False, True, True, False, False]

>>> [2*y_v+y_p for y_v, y_p in zip(y_valid, y_pred)]
[2, 0, 3, 1, 0, 2]
```

(Note: `zip` will take every `y_valid[i], y_pred[i]` for `i in range(min(len(y_valid), len(y_pred))`).

Answer (score 0):

Considering both the lists have the same length.

```py
y_valid = [True, False, True, False, False, True]
y_pred = [False, False, True, True, False, False]

CM = -1
for i in range(len(y_pred)):
    if (y_valid[i] == False) and (y_pred[i] == False):
        CM == 0
    elif (y_valid[i] == False) and (y_pred[i] == True):
        CM == 1
    elif (y_valid[i] == True) and (y_pred[i] == False):
        CM == 2
    elif (y_valid[i] == True) and (y_pred[i] == True):
        CM == 3
```

However, there are better ways in python to traverse lists or multiple lists.

Your code basically traverses over a `tuple`.
`(y_valid, y_pred)` is basically a `tuple`. Your code is traversing a tuple of each list.

```py
for i in (y_valid, y_pred):
    print(i)
```

Output:

```
[True, False, True, False, False, True]
[False, False, True, True, False, False]
```

The pythonic way to traverse over multiple lists is to `zip` them.

```py
y_valid = [True, False, True, False, False, True]
y_pred = [False, False, True, True, False, False]

CM = -1
for y_valid_i, y_pred_i in zip(y_valid, y_pred):
    if not y_valid_i and not y_pred_i:
        CM == 0
    elif not y_valid_i and y_pred_i:
        CM == 1
    elif y_valid_i and not y_pred_i:
        CM == 2
    elif y_valid_i and y_pred_i:
        CM == 3
```

However, the way you have used the variable `CM`, you're likely to run into more errors.

Comment: I copied your Code in new file, but it only returned CM = [ ]

Comment: Declare `CM = -1` outside the for loop. I have updated my answer. Hopefully, this'll work for you. @Changer

Comment: This just returned CM = -1. Thanks for your efforts in any way! Urban provided me the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

```py
y_valid = [True, False, True, False, False, True]
y_pred = [False, False, True, True, False, False]

for i in (y_valid, y_pred):
  print(i)
```

returns

```py
[True, False, True, False, False, True]
[False, False, True, True, False, False]
```

so python sees `(y_valid, y_pred)` as a tuple.
try:

```py
for i in range(len(y_valid)):
    # Code comes here
```

or

```py
for i in range(len(y_pred)):
    # Code comes here
```

Comment: It's a `tuple` and not a `generator`.

Comment: Sorry, I'll fix it.

Comment: thanks for your help, the solution helped me partly but only tackled half of the Problem. Anyway Urban provided me with full solution. Thanks for your Effort!